# MVC Membership database to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I create a new MVC application with EF, it creates all the views, models, controllers and logic for users to be able to log in, change passwords etc. The data is held in a MDF file in the app_data directory.

I used this for my users, and then had my own SQL Server 2008 database which was created code first using EF for all my other tables. When I wanted to reference a user from a table within this database, I used the ApplicationUser.Id.

Doing it this way, I have not got a foreign key between the table that holds the users and any other table in my custom DB, but thats a different topic.

The question I have, is how I can I stop this happening every time I create a new application, and how do I fix the issue I have now.

I have two different databases, when I just need one.  have one database in SQL Server (which is what I want) and one in a file which I cannot convert to SQL Server as it was created in 2012, and I am using 2008 SQL Server.

I am wanting to now deploy this on a server where all data is read from SQL Server.

The way I see it, I need to somehow get all the tables it creates for Membership, and put them into the database I created, then change the connection string. However first off I don't know how I would do this, and second... WHY do I have to do this? How can I just have one database next time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and messing around, I have answered my own question and think it may be useful for others.

I am using MVC 5 with the default ASP.NET Identity for my users.

What I found is that if I changed the connection string to point to my SQL server, it will create the database for me (the one that was previously a file in my app directory).

I then added a connection string to the same database for the context I created and it created all the tables for that in the same database.

The result is that I have one database with all my tables in.

Comment: That's one of the big benefits of Code First!